# php pdo prepared insert with select

Tags: php, select, insert, pdo

this is a hard nut for me. I have following prepared "insert into" Postgres with php pdo

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        mytable (zuordnung_id,spielgen_id,spielvor_id) 
        VALUES
           (
            :zuordnung_id, 
            :spielgen_id,
            :spielvor_id
            )"; 


$q2 = $objDb->prepare($sql); 

$q2->execute(array(':zuordnung_id'  => 5005,
                   ':spielgen_id'   => 5000,
                   ':spielvor_id'   => $_POST['User']
                      ));
```

How can I change :zuordnung_id (here with 5005) to a select statement which gives me the last number in mytable? Something like

```
':zuordnung_id'  => SELECT max(zuordnung_id) + 1
```

With kind regards,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

**you don't need no last number**

You have to setup auto_increment index for your table